# python image slicing using np.arange

Tags: python, image, numpy

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((321, 481, 3))
h, w = img.shape[:2]
new_h, new_w = 300, 400

top = np.random.randint(0, h-new_h)
left = np.random.randint(0, w - new_w)

print(top, left)

id_y = np.arange(top, top+new_h, 1)
id_x = np.arange(left, left+new_w, 1)

dst = img[id_y, id_x]
```

I want to slice an image of (321,481,3) into (300,400,3). Usually, I use `img[:300, :400, :]`, but I wanted the starting point to be random, So I tried writing the code differently.

But an Index error occurred.

```
id_y = np.arange(top, top_new_h, 1)[:, np.newaxis]
```

When I add the axis like this, slicing is done properly, but I'm curious about the principle behind adding the axis like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on broadcasting where you need every pair of indices to index into your image array. When both arrays are 1D arrays, the broadcast doesn't happen. You can fix this as you have done by adding a new axis (equivalent: `[:,None]`) or using [`np.xi_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html).

```py
dst = img[np.xi_(id_y, id_x)]
```